# Как получить массив из двух массивов, минуя повторяющиеся элементы?

Tags: javascript

Уважаемые не подскажите или не подтолкнете к верному решению.
Есть два массива

```
["школа", "дом", "сад", "колледж"]
["школа", "город", "сад", "колледж", "улица"]
```

в результате нужен один массив из эти двух, в котором все дубликаты удаляются,
то есть в итоге, массив должен быть такой

```
["школа", "дом", "сад", "колледж", "город", "улица"]
```

поможет ли метод reduce?

Comment: может быть `arr.concat(arr2.filter(el => !~arr.indexOf(el)))` ?

Comment: спасибо! то что нужно!

Comment: могу оформить ответом, если угодно :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var first = ["школа", "дом", "сад", "колледж"],
  second = ["школа", "город", "сад", "колледж", "улица"];

var arr = [...first, ...second];

var unique = [...new Set(arr)];
```

С помощью ES6 :)

Answer (score 1):

Для второго массива запускаем цикл, в котором проверяем - существует ли очередной элемент в предыдущем массиве... если нет ( `-1` ) — добавляем.

```js
let arr1 = ["школа", "дом", "сад", "колледж"];
let arr2 = ["школа", "город", "сад", "колледж", "улица"];

arr2.forEach(function(e){
  if( arr1.indexOf(e) == -1 ){
    arr1.push( e );
  }
});

console.log( arr1 );
```